# Access a service from a custom validator in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-di

I need to access my custom http service from inside a static method, as example:

```
import {Control} from 'angular2/common';
import {HttpService} from './http.service';

class UsernameValidator {
    static usernameExist(control: Control): Promise<ValidationResult> { 
        ... /* Access my HTTPservice here */
    }
}
```

How can I access a service in this case?

Comment: Could you please put more snippet of your code?

Comment: What is HTTPService? Put snippet of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another approach consists in returning a function. This way this function can have access to `HttpService` instance provided during creation:

```
class UsernameValidator {
  static createUsernameExist(http:HttpService) {
    return (control: Control) => { 
      ... /* Access my HTTPservice here */
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use it like that:

```
validator: UsernameValidator.createUsernameExist(this.httpService)
```

Comment: When initializing FormControl like this:
`username: ['', [Validators.required, UsernameValidator.createUsernameExist(this.httpService)]]`

I'm receiving an error "TypeError: UsernameValidator.createUsernameExist is not a function", how to make this work?

Comment: I'm following this example and I can see the log output of each case but my field is never valid. What should the service call look like? This is what I'm using. return (control: Control) => { 
      ... /* Access my HTTPservice here */
 return myService.getStuff().subscribe( data => {

  if(bad){
  return {bad:true}
}else {
 return null;
}
 }
    }

Answer (score 3):

```
class UsernameValidator {
    constructor(http:HttpService){}

    usernameExist(control: Control): Promise<ValidationResult> { 
        ... /* Access my HTTPservice here */
    }
}
```

then use it like

```
validator: new UsernameValidator(http).usernameExist
```

The `HttpService` needs to be injected in the component constructor instead and then passed to the manually created validator instance as shown above.

Comment: So I have to create new objects for each async Validator ? Would it be a good idea to implement my validator like the built-in `Validators.minLength(12)` and pass the http as the parameter ?

Comment: Sure, if you use it as directive than the `HttpService` can be injected directly. I assumed FormBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, after it I implemented the same thing Thierry gave, so I accepted his answer.

Comment: is this still the way to go? I would hope that Validators could be instatiated and dependency-injected automatically (I dont want to call 'new')

Comment: There is nothing wrong with new, but you can also make it a service and inject it. It's up to you which way you chose.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Günter Zöchbauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35505846/5583283) this is how I implemented my validator to access services from inside the `AsyncValidatorFn` ...

> IMHO it seems cleaner to let the DI inject the service dependencies directly into the validator class instead of passing the dependencies to a static method from the consumer component to create the `AsyncValidatorFn`.

**Create your injectable validator class**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, AsyncValidatorFn, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable
export class UsernameValidator {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpService,
  ) { }

  usernameExists: AsyncValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
    // access your HttpService here...
  }
}
```

**Provide validator for injection in your module declaration**

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    UsernameValidator, // register your validator for injection
  ],
})
export class UserModule { }
```

**Set validator function in your component form**

```js
constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  private usernameValidator: UsernameValidator, // inject your validator
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: [
      null, // initial value
      [Validators.required], // sync validators
      [this.usernameValidator.usernameExists], // async validators
    ],
  });
}
```